# How would I replace this function with a regex replace

Tags: java, regex

I have a file name with this format yy_MM_someRandomString_originalFileName.

example:

```
02_01_fEa3129E_my Pic.png
```

I want replace the first 2 underscores with `/` so that the example becomes:

```
02/01/fEa3129E_my Pic.png
```

That can be done with replaceAll, but the problem is that files may contain underscores as well.

```
@Test
void test() {

    final var input = "02_01_fEa3129E_my Pic.png";

    final var formatted = replaceNMatches(input, "_", "/", 2);

    assertEquals("02/01/fEa3129E_my Pic.png", formatted);
}

private String replaceNMatches(String input, String regex,
                               String replacement, int numberOfTimes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
        input = input.replaceFirst(regex, replacement);
    }
    return input;
}
```

I solved this using a loop, but is there a pure regex way to do this?

EDIT: this way should be able to let me change a parameter and increase the amount of underscores from 2 to n.

Comment: `input.replaceFirst("^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_", "$1/$2/")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups and use those in the replacement where the match of the `_` will be replaced by `/`

```
^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_
```

Replace with:

```
$1/$2/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3l0fMR/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/I53cpp)

For example:

```
String regex = "^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_";
String string = "02_01_fEa3129E_my Pic.png";
String subst = "$1/$2/";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
String result = matcher.replaceFirst(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

Result

```
02/01/fEa3129E_my Pic.png
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to completely rewrite the regex if I wanted the first 3 underscores . instead?

Comment: @RyanS. You could add a third group and also refer to that in the replacement https://regex101.com/r/3l0fMR/2

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution has few problems:

1. It is **inefficient** - because each `replaceFirst` need to start from beginning of string so it needs to iterate over same starting characters many times.
2. It has a **bug** - because of point 1. while iterating from beginning instead of last modified place, we can replace value which was inserted previously.

   For instance if we want to replace single character two times, each with `X` like `abc` -> `XXc` after code like

   ```
   String input = "abc";
   input = input.replaceFirst(".", "X"); // replaces a with X -> Xbc
   input = input.replaceFirst(".", "X"); // replaces X with X -> Xbc
   ```

   we will end up with `Xbc` instead of `XXc` because second `replaceFirst` will replace `X` with `X` instead of `b` with `X`.

To avoid that kind of problems you can rewrite your code to use `Matcher#appendReplacement` and `Matcher#appendTail` methods which ensures that we will iterate over input *once* and can replace each matched part with value we want

```
private static String replaceNMatches(String input, String regex,
                               String replacement, int numberOfTimes) {

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while(i++ < numberOfTimes && m.find() ){
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement); // replaces currently matched part with replacement, 
                                              // and writes replaced version to StringBuilder 
                                              // along with text before the match
    }
    m.appendTail(sb); //lets add to builder text after last match
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Usage example:

```
System.out.println(replaceNMatches("abcdefgh", "[efgh]", "X", 2)); //abcdXXgh
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was looking at this exact problem as well(looking for a generic solution).
I should probably do research into the Matcher class

Comment: BTW `appendReplacement` also supports *replacement* notation supported by `String#replaceAll` and `String#replaceFirst` like `$x` to reuse match from group `x` which makes `$` special character there. To escape it you would need to use `\$` (written in string literal as `"\\$"`), or let Matcher generate escaped string with `Matcher.quoteReplacement`.